# script (.sh) will not terminate

Tags: conky

I have a script file (start-conky.sh).  It executes correctly, but when I do a "ps -u " it shows as still a PID, which I'm assuming means it is still in memory.  Unless I do a "kill " it just stays there.  It is not causing any problem.  I'm just curious as to how to get the script to terminate after it executes.  I've listed the script below.  I really don't know that much about writing programs, so I'm sure there are mistakes.  Can anyone help?

Title: start-conky.sh "the title is just listed here it is not in the script"

```
#!/bin/bash

conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config1 & conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config2

exit
```

Comment: Uh, sorry.  How do you accept answers.  I've taken most all of the questions that were answered and used the info successfully.  If I have miss some protocol, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, I see it and will make use of it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a script is run, each line is executed one at a time and each must complete before the next one starts.  The `&` character after a command launches the command in the background allowing the next statement to be executed immediately without waiting for the previous one to finish.

So, your script is launching one instance of `conky` in the background using the config1 file and then launching another instance of `conky` in the foreground using the config2 file and then waits for that instance to finish before processing the next `exit` line.  If you change your script to have a `&` after each `conky` command like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config1 &
conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config2 &

exit
```

...it will not wait for them to finish before processing the `exit` command.

As John and Eliah stated, `&&` is used to chain two commands together with the second one executing only if the first one completed successfully.  This is generally done from the command line as opposed to a script.  This explains why after you made this change the second instance of conky never launched.  The first one never finished so that the second could start.

I hope that clears some stuff up.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation.  I made the changes and it works perfect.  Thanks again.  Is there some document, book, or web site that you could recommend for learning basic programming in Linux?

Comment: If you want to learn more about Bash scripting, here is a good beginner-level guide: http://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/

If you want to learn some more general purpose programming, Python is pretty easy to get started with: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_2.6

Answer (score 2):

What is that `&` supposed to do?
The way you use it it will send `conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config1` in the background.

Comment: Yes. If your intent was to first run `conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config1` and then if it completes without error run `conky -c ~/Conky/scripts/config2` the connector you want to use is `&&` not `&`.

Comment: Thanks, like I said I really don't know much on writing programs, so I used "&" instead of "&&" out of ignorance.  Thanks for the info, I appreciate it.

Comment: OK, when I put "&&" in place of "&" the second part of the script never launches.

Comment: @user18432 If you want to run a 2nd command while the 1st command is still running, then `&` is what you want. The 1st command does not complete until conky has exited, so if you wanted the 2nd command to run before conky had exited, you could use `&&`. Then the 2nd command would execute *if the first `conky` instance reported that it had run successfully*. But do you really want to run 2 instances of `conky` at the same time? If you want is to run `conky` once, with 2 configuration files (`config1` and `config2`), you could try `conky -c config1 -c config2` (I'm not sure if that will work).